# Install python package from private pypiserver

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pypi

I have setup a pypiserver behind an nginx proxy which uses htpasswd for authentication. I am currently able to upload sdists, but I can't figure out how to download them. I want to be able to download them when running `setup.py test` and somehow by using `pip`. Is this possible?

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    private

[private]
repository = https://example.com/pypi
username = remco
password = mypass
```

To make it extra hard the server is currently using a non verified ssl connection.

I tried the following setup based on http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#setuptools-package-index, but the only documentation on this is 'XXX'

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

from setuptools import setup


setup(
    name='asd',
    version='0.0.1',
    package_index='https://example.com/pypi/simple',
    test_suite='test',
    tests_require=['foo==0.0.1'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server certificate had to be setup properly.
For uploading using pip one must create a valid `~/.pypirc` file:

```
[distutils]
index-servers = example

[example]
repository = https://example.com/pypi
username = myname
password = mypass
```

For installing packages one needs to add the following section to `.pip/pip.conf`

```
[global]
extra-index-url = https://myname:mypass@example.com/pypi/simple
```

As knitti noted in a previous answer it is also possible to user `index-url` instead of `extra-index-url`. This does mean that the cheese shop is not used as a second server.

For using a private server with setuptools unittesting you need to add the following to your `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...
    dependency_links=[
        'https://myname:mypass@example.com/pypi/packages/'
    ])
```

Answer (score 7):

for using your index with `pip` create `~/.pip/pip.conf` with this content:

```
[global]
index-url = https://remco:mypass@build.d-centralize.nl/pypi/simple
cert = /etc/ssl/certs/your_cert_CA.pem
```

A little bit documentation on `pip.conf` is [here](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#configuration) and on pypiserver [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiserver#configuring-pip-easy-install)

Perhaps you can also try using `package_index='https://user:pass@example.com/pypi/simple`
in `setup.py`.

Comment: I think the index-url seems alright, but I get errors about the ssl certificate. I should probably get that fixed first anyway. About the package_index kwarg; setuptools complains it is an invalid argument. I have nu clue what to use instead

Comment: I added the line about making your CA known to pip, so that it doesn't complain.