# How to specify recursive dependencies in setup.py?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, setuptools, setup.py

I’m having difficulties understanding and implementing a few details of Python packaging using [`pip`](https://pypi.org/project/pip/) and [`setuptools`](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/).

Suppose I have three projects, `A` and `B` and `C` each of which is its own package and hosted in its own code repo. They also depend on each other, i.e. `A` is imported by `B`, and `B` is imported by `C`. Each package has a set of *direct* dependencies (i.e. directly imported other packages) and a set of *indirect* dependencies (i.e. packages imported by the directly dependent packages). These dependencies are a graph, not a tree.

For package `A`, should [setup.py](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/#packaging-your-project) contain only the directly dependent packages? Same for package `B`? When I then `pip install C` I noticed that `B` gets installed, but not `A`. I suppose that is because `A` is an indirect dependency for `C`.

I don’t really like the idea of storing a [`pip freeze`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_freeze/) in each package (inflexible and conflicts loom), but it seems that `pip` does not resolve the dependency graph recursively (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110449/can-pip-install-packages-recursively-from-requirements-txt#comment-44594626)). The [`snakebasket`](https://github.com/prezi/snakebasket) project attempted to address that problem, but is stale now; the [dependency-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46320277/why-is-dependency-links-in-setup-py-deprecated) option has been deprecated.

What is the proper and recommended way of handling this?

**Addendum** I forgot to mention that *none* of the packages (`A`, `B`, `C`) are available through the official [PyPi](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) repo, but live in private Github repos. Thus, for example `B`’s setup.py contains

```
install_requires=(
    …,
    A==1.0.0,
    …,
    )

dependency_links=[                                                                                        
    f"https://{github_token}@github.com/repo/A/archive/v1.0.0.tar.gz#egg=A-1.0.0",
    ],
```

and `C` contains a similar setup for package `B`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to specify recursive dependencies in `setup.py`?

Don't.

> What is the proper and recommended way of handling this?

`setup.py` should list the **direct** dependencies under `install_requires=[...]`. Do not list the transitive dependencies. And do not pin the dependencies here (though, in some cases, you may want to specify an upper or lower bound to ensure a compatible version is collected).

> When I then `pip install C` I noticed that `B` gets installed, but not `A`.

Then `B` is not correctly specifying the dependency on `A`.  Check again the metadata of `B`.

It *is* true that pip sometimes fails to resolve the dependency tree correctly, and there is an [open issue about that](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/988) since 2013, but you won't see it in a simple C -> B -> A dependency graph, only in some more pathological cases.

Check out my project [`johnnydep`](https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep) to render the dep tree and indicate where you're missing a "branch" in the package metadata.

Comment: I apologize, I should have mentioned that the packages live in a private repo. See also the **Addendum** above 

Comment: Yes, that was critical info to include! `dependency_links` has been deprecated for some time. The best approach is to host packages to a package index - not necessarily PyPI, it can be a private index - rather than trying to depend direct from github (which does not satisfy the [Simple Repository API](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0503/) and so will not work well with `pip`).

Comment: Thanks! Can you recommend such a private index or will I have to host one myself? Is [this article](https://packaging.python.org/guides/hosting-your-own-index/) still valid?

Comment: Yes that article is still valid. I recommend using a [devpi-server](https://github.com/devpi/devpi).

Comment: One more question: is it possible to specify a private index in setup.py? I see that `pip -i` would work, or adding `index-url` to `~/.pip/pip.conf` ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052288/install-python-package-from-private-pypiserver#22053466)). However, I think it would make much sense to specify my private index server as part of setup.py (I think `dependency_links` handled that). Also, what do you think of [this approach](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-use-github-as-a-pypi-server-1c3b0d07db2)?

Comment: No, it is not possible. The *user* has to opt-in to using a non-standard index, not the package. It will be too easy for hackers to distribute malicious code if you could put in the `setup.py` metadata to get a dependency from some random website instead of from PyPI.

Comment: As for the article, no, I do not think much of that approach using github.com as a package index. It looks hacky and lame. There are perfectly good and free open source index servers available for this, no need to abuse a version control 
system for the same (it's like using a screwdriver to hammer a nail: github is for managing source code, not distributing packages). Further, an index should ideally support search, upload, json api, metadata, etc..  and user would still need to opt-in to the --extra-index-url anyway, so it doesn't really help in your setup.py either.

Answer (score 0):

> For package A, should `setup.py` contain only the directly dependent packages?

Yes. Separation of concerns: every package should list dependencies it requires. Subpackages should care for themselves.

> When I then `pip install C` I noticed that B gets installed, but not A.

Can you show an example? I have a different experience.

> it seems that pip does not resolve the dependency graph recursively (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28110449/can-pip-install-packages-recursively-from-requirements-txt#comment-44594626)).

The answer from 2015 is outdated. `pip install` and `pip download` installs and downloads dependencies recursively.

Comment: I apologize, I should have mentioned that the packages live in a private repo. See also the **Addendum** above 